When does this sequence of sums converge to $0$?
Let $0 < \alpha < 1$. Consider the following sequence:
$$
a_n = \alpha^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i(i+1)\alpha^i}
$$
I tried to calculate numerically and it seems that even for small values of $\alpha$, this sequence $a_n \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$. But the values are very small so I do not fully trust numerical calculations.
Can it be proved that for all $0 < \alpha < 1$ the sequence $\{a_n\}$ converges to $0$?

We have $$a_n=\alpha^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i(i+1)\alpha^i}=\alpha^n \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)\alpha^i}+\alpha^n \sum_{i=\lfloor n/2\rfloor}^{n} \frac{1}{i(i+1)\alpha^i}=b_n+c_n$$
Now, $$c_n\leq \alpha^n \sum_{i=\lfloor n/2\rfloor}^{n} \frac{1}{i(i+1)\alpha^n}= \sum_{i=\lfloor n/2\rfloor}^{n} \frac{1}{i(i+1)}$$
Because the series $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{i(i+1)}$ converges, by Cauchy's Criterion, $\displaystyle\sum_{i=\lfloor n/2\rfloor}^{n} \frac{1}{i(i+1)}\to 0$ and thus $c_n\to 0$.
As for $b_n$, notice that $\big(\text{ as } \lfloor n/2\rfloor -1<\lfloor n/2\rfloor\leq n/2\big)$ $$b_n=\alpha^n \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)\alpha^i}\leq \alpha^n\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)\alpha^{n/2}}=\alpha^{n/2}\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)}$$
The second factor is bounded because the aforementioned series converges. As $0<\alpha<1$, we have that $\alpha^{n/2}\to 0$, which implies that the right term converges to $0$, and so $b_n\to 0$.
Given that $b_n,c_n\to 0$, it follows that $a_n\to 0$.

Great! Btw, the sum from $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ to n is equal to $1/\lfloor n/2 \rfloor - 1/(n+1)$. This is just to be explicit, Cauchy's argument is fully valid.

We have that by $x=\frac1{\alpha}>1$
$$a_n = \alpha^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i(i+1)\alpha^i}=\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x^i}{i(i+1)}}{x^n} \to 0$$
indeed by Stolz-Cesaro
$$\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{x^i}{i(i+1)}-\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x^i}{i(i+1)}}{x^{n+1}-x^n}=\frac{  \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+2)}}{x^{n+1}-x^n}=\frac{x}{(x-1)(n+1)(n+2)}\to 0$$

More in general, by the same approach, we have that for any sequence $b_n\to0$
$$\alpha^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{b_i}{\alpha^i}\to 0$$

Much more concise proof than that by @julio-puerta. On the other hand, the good by-product of the previous solution is the upper bound on the sequence.

@YauhenYakimenka Yes of course! Mine is a standard calculus solution. Bye

Note that in the same way we have that $\alpha^n \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^{\beta}\alpha^i}\to 0$ for any $\beta>1$.

I meant for any $\beta >0$ of course!

The question can be generalized. Namely let  $0<a_n\nearrow \infty$ and $b_n\ge 0,$ $ \sum b_n<\infty.$  Then $${1\over a_n}\sum_{j=1}^na_jb_j\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0 $$ Indeed,  WLOG we may assume that $b_n\le 1.$ Fix $\varepsilon>0.$ There is $K$ such that $\sum_{j=K+1}^\infty b_j<{\varepsilon\over 2}.$ Once $K$ is fixed, there is $N$ such that   $${1\over  a_N}\sum_{j=1}^Ka_j<{\varepsilon \over 2}$$ Then for $n> N$ we get $${1\over a_n}\sum_{j=1}^na_j b_j= {1\over a_n}\sum_{j=1}^Ka_jb_j+\sum_{j=K+1}^n b_j{a_j\over a_n}\quad (*)\\ \le{1\over a_N}\sum_{n=1}^Ka_j+\sum_{j=K+1}^\infty b_j<\varepsilon$$ which completes the proof. Now we can apply the above to $a_n={1\over \alpha^{n}}$ and $b_n={1\over n(n+1)}.$
As suggested by @user, in the particular case $a_n=x^n$, $x>1,$
the condition on $b_n$ can be relaxed to $b_n\to 0.$ Indeed, we choose $K$ so that $b_{j}<{\varepsilon (x-1)\over 2x}$ for $j>K.$  Then $N$ is chosen as above to make the first sum in $(*)$ less than ${\varepsilon\over 2}.$ Next for $n>N$ we get
$$\sum_{j=K+1}^n b_j{a_j\over a_n}<{\varepsilon (x-1)\over 2x}\sum_{j=K+1}^nx^{j-n}<{\varepsilon(x-1)\over 2x}\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^{-j}={\varepsilon\over 2}$$

Nice generalization! It seems that it is not necessary that $\sum b_n<\infty$, it suffices $b_n \to 0$.

@user Thanks. Unfortunately the condition $b_n\to 0$ is not sufficient. For $b_n={1\over n}$ and $a_n=\sqrt{n}$ the expression tends to $\infty.$

Yes of course but I'm referring to the case of the present question with $a_n=\frac1{\alpha^n}$.

@user You are right. In this particular case the weaker condition suffices. I will extend the answer.

Yes I added it in a comment but I’ll update the answer later with this extension. Thanks, bye
